# Transitioning between text values with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, transition

Is there any way to transition between text values for a particular element - e.g. fading between them or something similar?  I've found no relevant references to this, but D3 seems built for this kind of thing.  This jsfiddle may assist: http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/2wJr7/

```
<p>Intro text - click mouse on this text</p>
<script>
var i = 0;
var data = ['text 1','text 2','text 3','text 4','text 5','text 6','text 7','text 8'];

var change = d3.select('p').on("mousedown", function(){transition();});

function transition() {
    change.transition().duration(1000).text(data[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `opacity` to 0 and then to 1 in two connected transitions:

```
change.transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .text(data[i]);
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wJr7/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var data = ['text 1','text 2','text 3','text 4','text 5','text 6','text 7','text 8'];

var change = d3.select('p').on("mousedown", function(){transition();});

function transition() {
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++)
    change
        .transition()
        .delay(i * 1000)
        .duration(500)
        .text(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is more beautiful than changing opacity](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/bPtVD/)

```
function transition() {
    d3.select('text').transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("font-size","1px")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .text(data[i])
        .style("font-size","16px");
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks VividD, I like it. Works well for center-aligned text.